# Unexpected termination of Bind in Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Tags: 10.04, bind

I've got a VPS Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS with all kinds of servers on it. One in particular is Bind9 which from time to time is stopped without any reason. For instance it was stopped yesterday which I started it manually (through SSH). But today I woke up to find the same daemon to be stopped.

I'll be grateful if someone could guide me to the right direction how to start debugging this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been digging through the Lucid Bind9 package and I think Bind9 uses `/var/log/syslog` as its default log. If the `/etc/init.d/bind9` is crashing with an error that outputs, I'd hope it shows up there.

If it's crashing before it can close, your only option might be running it manually (rather than the service). You'll need to pick through the `$OPTIONS` that get set up in the service file and run `/usr/sbin/named` with them. You also need to tell `resolveconf` about the new nameserver. It's a bit tough to unravel but it's all in that service file.

The other option is you could assume it's a weird bug that's been fixed since. 12.04 is a minor version up and 14.04 (which will be released this month) is running 9.9. The other side of that argument is that they might not have fix it and it might have exotic, new bugs too... But support for 10.04 expires next year so it's something you'll need to consider anyway.

Comment: How can I make sure which file the error log is printed to? I read the `/var/log/syslog` file and I did find few entries regarding the bind but none of them where errors. I wonder if errors are actually flushed there.